# UTF8 troubles in a php contact form

Tags: php, syntax-error

Here is my contact function :

```
public static function contact_anon()
{
    $form = new Form('contact_anon');

    $form->field('email', 'text', array
    (
        'max_length'    =>  45,
        'valid_email'   =>  true
    ));

    $form->field('message', 'textarea', array
    (
        'max_length'    =>  400,
        'min_length'    =>  25
    ));

    if($data = $form->validate())
    {
        $envoi = array
        (
            'message'   =>  $data['message'],
            'email' =>  $data['email']
        );

        mail('mymail@gmail.com', lang('contact_anon'), lang('contact_anon_text', $envoi), 'From: noreply@'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    }

    return $form;
}
```

Then I have this other php file with the content text that will be sent + the message from the form :

```
<?php
fw::$lang = array_merge(fw::$lang, array
(   
'contact_anon_text'     =>  "You have been contacted :

    Message : {message}

    Mail : {email}"
));
```

The form is working well, but the `{message}` doesn't display correctly, for example :

```
j\'Ã©cris avec des accents pour voir si Ã§a marche.
```

The website has a UTF8 charset, but I don't know about php, I tried the following :

```
'message'   =>  htmlentities((utf8_decode($data['message']), ENT_QUOTES),
```

But it returns :

```
syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting '('
```

I know there is hundreds of posts about UTF8, I checked them, read the php mnual and sql manual, but couldn't understand so much as I am a beginner and not english speaker.

I also have the same problem when sending a text field to the database, eventhough the database is using utf8_general_ci. So I guess it's definitely a problem with my php code. I am using a MVC scripts with controllers. To solve partially the SQL problem, I use :

```
return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
    ....
db::escape($username)
```

So the output is correct, but I had prefer to configure php to use UT8 and allows special characters like french accents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving your file with encoding UTF-8.
If you are using visual studio go to File, Save As, Save With Encoding and choose Unicode(UTF-8 without signature).

Comment: I'm using notepad++ , so I tried "encode in UTF8 (without BOM)" and now I got like chinese characters instead of accents `茅茅茅茅`

Comment: Should I convert the php file that contains the contact function or only the language file ?

Comment: Should I encode all my php files to utf8 ?

Comment: The language file with encoding will be enough.